# Paging code snippet

Tags: c, operating-system, paging

I attempted a question which related to OS. But I can't understand what is happening.

Question is

An operatiing system allocates 100 memory frames for each process. The page sie of this system is 1000 bytes. The memory is byte addressable. A Programmer notice that while running the following program the computer continuously reads the hard disk even though t does not have any instruction to read or write files. He also notices that the program takes unusually long time to complete.

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char[1000][1000];
    for(i = 0;i<1000;i++)
        for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
            x[j][i]=125;
    return 0;
}
```

a. If x[0][0] of the two dimensional array is stored at the virtual address 1000 what is the virtual address of x[1][0]

```
My ans was 2000
```

b. The programmer notices that by modifying one line of the above program he can reduce the number of disk reads. Modify that line.

Can any one please explain me this question

Comment: Hint: check how the loop variables are being used to index the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* that changing the inner statement to

```
x[i][j]=125;
```

will reduce the writing on the drive.  You'd be setting the memory sequentially rather than jumping all over the place.